# Executing several snapshots of one VMWare

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, snapshot

I have set up a VM with several snapshots. The size is quite large (~40 GB). Now I would like to run several tests on that operating system, but it seems VMWare Workstation 8.0.6 can only execute one snapshot at a time.

I don't want to copy the whole VM just for running another test. Is there a way to run several snapshots at the same time?

As far as I understand, each snapshot has its own hard disk file, so there should not be a conflict.

**Update**

I want to run different snapshots at once, not one snapshot multiple times (although that would also be nice).

Comment: VMWare doesn't support what you want.  You would have to either create a full clone of the virtual machine or a shallow clone both can be done through the snapshot manager.  While the snapshot files are seperate, the snapshots all use the same main file, which means running multiple virtual machines would cause a major conflict ( and the sole major reason what you want isn't possible )

Comment: What do you mean execute one snapshot at a time ? Only restore One snapshot at a time ?

Comment: @Lawrence: not only restore the snapshots, but also click the Play button so that I can work with it.

Comment: @Ramhound: the main file is accessed read-only, isn't it? I hoped that Windows file system caching would be good enough to handle parallel read accesses to that file. RAM shall not be an issue. I can have 16 GB.

Comment: @ThomasW. - Its very unlikely the main file is accessed as a read-only file.  This problem would exist on VMWare on OS X and Linux, the problem itself, has nothing to do with Windows nor the amount of memory you have installed in the system.

Comment: I have not had much experience with VMWare Workstation, but I have had some with ESXi, and AFAIK snapshots aren't actually copies of the main file, but delta files which keep track of what changes between the last snapshot or the main vmdk file, and the new snapshot. It doesn't actually store *everything* in the snapshot, hence why what you want can't be done. You will have to clone the VM to do what you want to do.

Comment: @Ramhound: when we're talking about the main file, is it the initial VMDK hard disk file? If someone writes to that file, it would affect all snapshots, even those which are not running... The snapshot -0000x.VMDKs store only the differences, right?